# How can we link combobox with database table?

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I have a combox called comboBox2 and i want to fill this combobox with a column named 'Stud_Name' of my database table called 'Student_Table'
I use the following code:

```
void Fillcombo()
{
    string constring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\ChaCha\\ChaCha\\chacha.mdf;Integrated Security=False";
    string query = "select * from database.Student_Table";
    SqlConnection condb = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand cmddb = new SqlCommand(query, condb);
    SqlDataReader myreader;

    try
    {
        condb.Open();
        myreader = cmddb.ExecuteReader();
        while(myreader.Read())
        {
            string sName = myreader.GetString("Stud_Name");
            comboBox2.Items.Add(sName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

But, I am getting an error message like this:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid
>   arguments.

How can I remove this error?
I use Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message is clearly says;

There is no overload of [`SqlDataReader.GetString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes `string` as a parameter.

This method takes `int` as a parameter which is the number of *zero-based* column that you want to get.

You need to put as an integer value which is `Stud_Name` column number in your query.

For example; if your `Stud_Name` is the first column of your `query`, you can use it like;

```
string sName = myreader.GetString(0);
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: Thanks.The error is gone. But, when I run the program, the combobox is still empty.

Comment: Are you sure your query returns data? Did you debug your code? Are you sure your `sName` have data?

Comment: No. I checked it. sName dont't have any data. What could be the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it. I just changed 'database.Student_Table' to 'Student_Table'.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the parameter you pass to the method called `GetString`. Uou should pass there the index of the column, you want to read from. Instead of doing this, you pass the name of the column. That's why you get this error message.

For more documentation, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks.The error is gone. But, when I run the program, the combobox is still empty.